# Passing data from view to controller asp.net core razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to create a simple asp.net core razor web site.

I have a cshtml page:

```
@page

@using RazorPages

@model IndexModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  <label for="age">How old are you?</label>
  <input type="text" asp-for="age">
  <br/>
  <label for="money">How much money do you have in your pocket?</label>
  <input type="text" asp-for="money">
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" id="Submit">
}
```

and a cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RazorPages
{
  public class IndexModel : PageModel
  {
    protected string money { get; set; }
    protected string age { get; set; }
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        return Page();
      }



      return RedirectToPage("Index");

    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to pass age and money to the cs file and then pass it back to the cshtml file in order to display it on the page after the submit button sends a get request. How can I implement this?

Updated:
The following code does not work.
index.cshtml.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



namespace RazorPages
{
  public class IndexModel : PageModel
  {
    [BindProperty]
    public decimal Money { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
 /*     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        return Page();
      }*/
    this.Money = Money;
    this.Age = Age;







 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\murach\exercises\WriteText.txt", 
this.Money.ToString());
return RedirectToPage("Index", new { age = this.Age, money = this.Money});

    }
  }
}
```

and index.cshtml:

```
 @page
    @using RazorPages


    @model IndexModel

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
      <label for="Age">How old are you?</label>
      <input type="text" asp-for="Age">
      <br/>
      <label for="Money">How much money do you have in your pocket?</label>
      <input type="text" asp-for="Money">
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" id="Submit">


    }
    Money: @Model.Money
    Age: @Model.Age
```

Money and age show up as 0s on the page and file regardless of what you type in.

Comment: You want to redirect to the `Index` page and pass those properties to that Page?

Comment: I want to use the values that are in the inputs to display at the bottom of the form after a post request.

Comment: OK, I added my answer. Be careful: Right now, you're redirecting if the `ModelState` is valid, which means you'll get redirected onPost.

Comment: not 100% sure but I adding to @jAC answer, change protected for public on the bindable properties.

Comment: @BartCalixto: Indeed, otherwise it's not accessible from the `Page`, throwing `'Page.Age' is inaccessible due to its protection level`

Comment: The  posted solution did not work for me. See the updated section in the question.

Comment: You mixed a few things together now, I'll update my answer to make it more clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Append your .cshtml file with code that outputs the values you're filling via POST.

**MyPage.cshtml**

```
@page
@model IndexModel  
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <label for="Age">How old are you?</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="Age">
    <br />
    <label for="Money">How much money do you have in your pocket?</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="Money">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="Submit">  
}
Money: @Model.Money
Age: @Model.Age
```

Now add `[BindProperty]` to each property in your model, which you want to update from your `OnPost()`:

```
[BindProperty]
public int Age { get; set; }
[BindProperty]
public decimal Money { get; set; }
```

Furthermore, as [Bart Calixto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/826568/bart-calixto) pointed out, those properties have to be public in order to be accessible from your `Page`.

The `OnPost()` method is really simple, since ASP.NET Core is doing all the work in the background (thanks to the binding via `[BindProperty]`).

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    return Page();
}
```

So now, you can click on `Submit` and voila, the page should look like this:

[image: Razor Page Post]

Btw.: Properties are written with a [capital letter in the beginning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: As a small info: `return RedirectToPage("SomeOtherPage", new { age = this.Age, money = this.Money});` has been there in case you wanted to redirect this info to **another** page.

Comment: I am using an empty web site template. Your example is using a razor page template

Comment: Your example is also using Razor Pages. You tagged this post with [tag:razor-pages], your title contains razor pages and your code is a razor page (`@page`). What do you mean by empty web site template?

Comment: My code was missing the renderbody() function and the layout.cshtml, viewimports etc...