# Passing Value to Controller in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a requirement to pass value from view to controller in the `Html.BeginForm()`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeRole", "Login", null, FormMethod.Post, null, new { id = "SubmitRole" }))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()                                                                     
     @foreach (var item in (@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<UserRoleLevelDetails>("GetAllUsersList")))
     {
         //..
         if (@vr != @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Role").ToString())
         {
          <a class="@vr" id=@string.Format("{0}", @item.Role_Level_Name) onclick="Change_Role(this)">@vr</a><br />
         }
        //..
    }                                                                   
}

function Change_Role(e) {
    var ChangedRole = $(e).attr('class');         
    $('#UserMainRole').val(ChangedRole);
    $("#SubmitRole").submit();
     e.preventDefault();
};
```

So, while submitting I need to pass value of `ChangedRole` to the controller.

Comment: In what way does the code shown not work as expected?  What element is `$('#UserMainRole')` meant to reference?  Is it a form element which can contain a value?  Is it contained within the form?  When you debug in your browser, is that element's value updated?  What specifically fails?

Comment: maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872496/passing-data-from-view-to-controller-asp-net-core-razor-pages

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible unit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?